# Fixing File path with user input to create search for file function

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, automation

I have a bunch of CSV files with the name (modelnumber)_filter. The user is asked which model they are searching for so
example user input : *"1.3C-H4SL-D1"*
So then the file path will be loaded:

> "C:\Users\ADMIN-SURV\Desktop\data_pull\1.3C-H4SL-D1_filter.csv"

**EX CSV**

```
"Search Results"

"Summary"
"Saved on","12/10/2021 1:36:26 PM"
"Searched for","Avigilon (ONVIF) 2.0C-H5A-D1"
"In document","C:\Users\ADMIN-SURV\Desktop\data_pull\my.pdf"
"Number of document(s) found","1"              
"Number of instance(s) found","18"             

"File name","Title","Page","Search Instance"
"IslandView.pdf","","33","H5A-D1(3022506) Avigilon (ONVIF) 2.0C-H5A-D1 Unknown Logical ID:692 192.168.50.189 "
"IslandView.pdf","","55","H5A-D1(3022509) Avigilon (ONVIF) 2.0C-H5A-D1 Unknown Logical ID:657 192.168.60.243 "
"IslandView.pdf","","55","H5A-D1(3022547) Avigilon (ONVIF) 2.0C-H5A-D1 Unknown Logical ID:469 192.168.60.248 "
"IslandView.pdf","","55","H5A-D1(3022533) Avigilon (ONVIF) 2.0C-H5A-D1 Unknown Logical ID:700 192.168.50.190 "
"IslandView.pdf","","87","104 RIGHT ENTRY Avigilon (ONVIF) 2.0C-H5A-D1 Unknown 192.168.90.212 00:18:85:"
"IslandView.pdf","","87","101 LEFT ENTRY Avigilon (ONVIF) 2.0C-H5A-D1 192.168.50.243 00:18:85:2E:"
"IslandView.pdf","","87","H5A-D1(3022627) Avigilon (ONVIF) 2.0C-H5A-D1 Unknown Logical ID:55 192.168.60.249 "
"IslandView.pdf","","88","H5A-D1(3669534) Avigilon (ONVIF) 2.0C-H5A-D1 Unknown Logical ID:463 192.168.18.202 "
"IslandView.pdf","","94","103 LEFT ENTRY Avigilon (ONVIF) 2.0C-H5A-D1 Unknown 192.168.60.245 00:18:85:"
"IslandView.pdf","","146","104 RIGHT ENTRY Avigilon (ONVIF) 2.0C-H5A-D1 Unknown 192.168.90.212 00:18:85:"
"IslandView.pdf","","201","H5A-D1(3022509) Avigilon (ONVIF) 2.0C-H5A-D1 Unknown 192.168.60.243 00:18:85:"
"IslandView.pdf","","201","H5A-D1(3022506) Avigilon (ONVIF) 2.0C-H5A-D1 Unknown 192.168.50.189 00:18:85:"
"IslandView.pdf","","201","H5A-D1(3022533) Avigilon (ONVIF) 2.0C-H5A-D1 Unknown 192.168.50.190 00:18:85:"
"IslandView.pdf","","201","H5A-D1(3022547) Avigilon (ONVIF) 2.0C-H5A-D1 Unknown 192.168.60.248 00:18:85:"
"IslandView.pdf","","201","101 LEFT ENTRY Avigilon (ONVIF) 2.0C-H5A-D1 Unknown 192.168.50.243 00:18:85:"
"IslandView.pdf","","201","H5A-D1(3022622) Avigilon (ONVIF) 2.0C-H5A-D1 Unknown 192.168.60.245 00:18:85:"
"IslandView.pdf","","202","H5A-D1(3022627) Avigilon (ONVIF) 2.0C-H5A-D1 Unknown 192.168.60.249 00:18:85:"
"IslandView.pdf","","203","H5A-D1(3669534) Avigilon (ONVIF) 2.0C-H5A-D1 Unknown 192.168.18.202 00:18:85:"
```

Then a new file will also be created with that input as:

> "C:\Users\ADMIN-SURV\Desktop\data_pull\1.3C-H4SL-D1.txt"

Here is my code.

```
import csv
import re
import sys

new_file = input("What is the camera model? **Use Exact Casing and Symbols**")
file_path = "C:\\Users\\ADMIN-SURV\\Desktop\\data_pull\\filter_results\\"
end_path = file_path + new_file + ".txt"
print(end_path)

sys.stdout = open(end_path, 'x')
with open("C:\\Users\\ADMIN-SURV\\Desktop\\data_pull\\" + new_file + "_filter.csv") as fid:
    print(fid)
    input_file = csv.reader(fid)
    for row in input_file:
        if len(row) >= 4:
            if row[0] == 'File name':
                # skip the header row
                continue
            # m = re.match(r".*(.* [0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})", row[3])
            m = re.match(r'.*(.* [0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})', row[3])
            if m:
                print(m.group(1))
            else:
                print(row[3])

sys.stdout.close()
```

As of now when I run this code I get the following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\ADMIN-SURV\PycharmProjects\pdf_scraping\test_file.,py", line 28, in 
> with open("C:\Users\ADMIN-SURV\Desktop\data_pull\" + new_file + "_filter.csv") as fid:
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\ADMIN-SURV\Desktop\data_pull\1.3C-H4SL-D1_filter.csv'

The CSV file already exists and should be found with user input.
The .TXT file should be created with user input.

Comment: What is the exact Python version you are using/running?

Comment: @MaXiMkA Python 3.10.0

Comment: I copied your code-example and have 26 lines. Your error says line 28. Btw, it executed with a dummy .csv on 3.8.0

Comment: @MaXiMkA yes i removed some lines from the code on here because it was a lot of comments. and what do you mean a dummy csv file? It should only work if one already exists.

Comment: You didn't say anything about the .csv file's content, so I created a dummy one with 1,2,3,4 and a,b,c,d in the first 2 columns.

Comment: @MaXiMkA oh I understand now. When I run it now, it tries to save the .txt file as whatever the input is as the file type. For example: If I input "3.0C-H4A-D1-B" it comes back as "**TYPE** 3.0C-H4A-D1-B" rather than type = text document

Comment: My point was that without an exact input .csv file I can't reproduce your error :(

Comment: I threw the CSV results for one of the models into the question

Comment: @MaXiMkA I am also going to add my updated code above. But what does "<_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:\\Users\\ADMIN-SURV\\Desktop\\data_pull\\2.0C-H4A-D1-B_filter.csv' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>" mean? I looked it up, but why is it in my file now? It didn't say that in my CSV files before.

Comment: ..and you already have a solution, see? :) Never forget to supply any input files/information for your problems in the future. Good luck with Python!

Comment: @MaXiMkA thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you get

`<_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:\Users\maxim\PycharmProjects\FB_Books\data_pull\1.3C-H4SL-D1_filter.csv' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>`

is because of `sys.stdout = open(end_path, 'x')`.

`open(end_path, 'x')` returns

`<_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:\Users\maxim\PycharmProjects\FB_Books\data_pull\1.3C-H4SL-D1_filter.csv' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>`

So we're just going to clean up the logic a bit. We'll open the new file with `'x'` parameter (meaning it'll create the file if not created, and write. However, if it's already created, it won't allow to open and overwrite it)

Then using your logic, we'll just write the ip address to that file.

```
import csv
import re
import sys

new_file = input("What is the camera model? **Use Exact Casing and Symbols**")
file_path = "C:\\Users\\ADMIN-SURV\\Desktop\\data_pull\\filter_results\\"
end_path = file_path + new_file + ".txt"
print(end_path)

output_txt_file = open(end_path, 'x')
with open("C:\\Users\\ADMIN-SURV\\Desktop\\data_pull\\" + new_file + "_filter.csv") as fid:
    print(fid)
    input_file = csv.reader(fid)
    for row in input_file:
        if len(row) >= 4:
            if row[0] == 'File name':
                # skip the header row
                continue
            # m = re.match(r".*(.* [0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})", row[3])
            m = re.match(r'.*(.* [0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})', row[3])
            if m:
                print(m.group(1).strip())
                output_txt_file.write(m.group(1).strip() + '\n')
                
            else:
                print(row[3])

output_txt_file.close()
```

Comment: This worked thank you! Emailed for further correspondence

Comment: how can I extract the integers "481" from this line and print it instead of this whole string?

*"Detection: Unsupported 481 1.3C-H4SL-D1(1866954) Avigilon (ONVIF) 1.3C-H4SL-D1 Unknown"*

Each row will have different numbers and not all "481" so the code will have to be able to extract more than just "481"

Comment: Thank you for clarifying things. I had a feeling that the end_path attribute was incorrect, but I didn't have time for further debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Ran it with Python 3.8.0, the result was a file in ../filter_results with no extension. I changed it to be .txt and this is its content:

> <_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:\Users\maxim\PycharmProjects\FB_Books\data_pull\1.3C-H4SL-D1_filter.csv' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>

Comment: I am not quite following